# Email winform apps with multiple host

Tags: c#, winforms, sendmail

I want to send the mail on different domains name or host like gmail ,yahoo,live etc .from one winform apps.

```
try
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(txt_from.Text, txt_to.Text, txt_subject.Text, txt_message.Text);
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
    client.Port = 587;
    client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(txt_username.Text, txt_password.Text);
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    client.Send(mail);
    MessageBox.Show("Mail Sent !");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Gmail Sender");
}
```

Comment: suppose, anyone have gmail yahoo live etc. id , then how to code for multiple host ? system.net.mail only for one client

Comment: see, i have done one  window apps in that only gmail user can sent the mail to other domains . now, i want general code : suppose my id on gmail & my friend id on yahoo , when i will open this apps then mail sent easily because in that apps gmail smtp but my friend mail not sent because of smtp not matched for yahoo. so you tell me the general code for that

Comment: This is not a "gimme da codez" site. Nobody here will do your job for you (unless you pay them). Show us what you tried, show us what problem you had, and we'll be glad to help you fix the problem.

Comment: now this is my code for simple email sent apps from winform . now you please help me how to convert this single host to multiple host

Comment: It doesn't matter what your id is. You can send to any other email address. Your code should work fine to send to yahoo. What goes wrong when you try?

Comment: no no i want to sent the mail on gmail yahoo or any other domain from my yahoo id but this code for gmail . i want to common code for every host ?

Comment: You can send _from_ gmail to anywhere.

Comment: i want to code like this if i type the email id of any domain then mail will sent ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First host depend only by sender.So you can parse `txt_from.Text` to now what host you will need to use :

```
 private string GetHost(string SenderEmailAddress)
        {
            string host = "";
            try
            {
                if (SenderEmailAddress.Contains("@gmail."))
                    host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                else if (SenderEmailAddress.Contains("@live.") || SenderEmailAddress.Contains("@hotmail."))
                    host = "smtp.live.com";
                else if (SenderEmailAddress.Contains("@yahoo."))
                    host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            return host;
        }
```

**The** method above will deal with "three famous" ones, and additionally you can provide your user an optional manual host by a textbox in your form, Check [Send smtp email](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jv7eFcfWhWQ) because there is a trick for Yahoo case

Comment: can you merged your program with mine.
i have take one button and full code  behind on that . so please merged them all coding

Comment: sir code not working .
host is mention & what about port ? is it not compulsory to define in the code ?